# gulp Read all file names from folder and store in some file

Tags: gulp, gulp-concat, gulp-uglify

I am using "gulp-filenames" to get the file name, I followed the documentation what I found from [this site.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-filenames) It doesn't help :(

Please see below code

```
var filenames = require("gulp-filenames");

gulp.src('/*.js'))
   .pipe(filenames("javascript"));

filenames.get("javascript")
```

Basically I want to store all file name in one file.

=======================

## INPUT

- Folder

  1. myfile.js
  2. myfile1.js

=====================

## EXPECTED OUPTPUT

- Folder

  1. myfile.js
  2. myfile1.js
  3. javascript (Which contains the file name for example myfile.js and myfile1.js with path)

Comment: i am also looking for an answer to this :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the answer, with the "[gulp-filelist](https://github.com/cjroth/gulp-filelist)", I can get all filename.

Below are the code fore reference.

```
gulp.src(['../Scripts/Include/JavaScript/DatePicker.js', 
'../Scripts/Include/JavaScript/DatePicker_Plugins.js'])
      .pipe(filelist('filelist.json'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist"));
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved my question.  I simplified mine a bit with gulp.src('./textures/*.jpg') so I could always have a current list of available textures.